# Binding not working inside component in knockout.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I've made a component here:

```
ko.components.register('text-list', {
    viewModel: function (params) {
        var self = this;
        // Data
        this.name = ko.observable(params.name);
        this.info = params.info;
        this.items = params.items;
        this.isOpen = ko.observable(true);
        this.selectedItem = ko.observable('');

        // Behaviors
        this.selectFacet = function (item) {
            self.selectedItem = item;
            self.isOpen = false;
            alert("selectedItem: " + self.selectedItem + ", isOpen: " + self.isOpen);
        }.bind(this);

        this.useAny = function () {
            self.selectedItem = 'Any';
            self.isOpen = false;
            alert("selectedItem: " + self.selectedItem + ", isOpen: " + self.isOpen);
        }.bind(this);

        this.remove = function () {
            self.selectedItem = '';
            self.isOpen = true;
        }.bind(this);

    },
    template:
       //'<li class="list-group-item text-list-facet">\
        '<div class="row header-row">\
            <div class="col-md-12">\
                <div class="row">\
                    <div class="col-md-4">\
                        <p class="text-left">\
                            <b><small data-bind="text: name"></small></b>\
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign infoicon" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-bind="attr: { title: info }"></span>\
                        </p>\
                    </div>\
                    <div class="col-md-4">\
                        <p class="text-center selected-choice" data-bind="text: selectedItem"></p>\
                    </div>\
                    <div class="col-md-4">\
                        <p class="text-right">\
                            <span data-bind="visible: isOpen">\
                                <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" data-bind="click: useAny"><small>use any</small> <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>\
                            </span>\
                            <span data-bind="visible: !isOpen">\
                                <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" data-bind="click: remove"><small>remove</small> <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>\
                            </span>\
                        </p>\
                    </div>\
                </div>\
            </div>\
        </div>\
        <div class="row content-row" data-bind="visible: isOpen">\
            <div class="col-md-12">\
                <ul class="list-inline" data-bind="foreach: items">\
                    <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-link specul" data-bind="text: $data, click: $parent.selectFacet"></button></li>\
                </ul>\
            </div>\
        </div>'
    //</li>'
});
```

Now I'm trying to create a component and pass in a view model, like so:

```
var textListViewModel = function () {
            this.name = 'Test Section';
            this.info = 'This is a tooltip';
            this.items = ['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3'];
        };

//apply with a viewmodel
        var $nw = $('<li class="list-group-item text-list-facet"><text-list params="name: name, info: info, items: items"></text-list></li>');
        $('#test-ul').append($nw);
        ko.applyBindings(textListViewModel, $nw[0]);
```

Now this seems great and makes the item appear as it should and populates what should be populated.  The problem is that when I try to use those functions I defined in the template like "selectFacet", "useAny", and "remove", it doesn't seem to do anything (but the alerts work and have the correct values).

My aim is that on say "selectFacet" is that I'm updating isOpen and selectedItem which are both referenced in the template, e.g.

```
<p class="text-center selected-choice" data-bind="text: selectedItem"></p>
```

and

```
<span data-bind="visible: isOpen"> ... <span data-bind="visible: !isOpen">
```

Now maybe I'm missing something, but I thought that these elements should be bound to those variables defined in my view model, so that upon a change to them, it would update here.  But upon changing selectedItem from '' to whatever was clicked, nothing appears to change on the screen!  Same with toggling isOpen from true to false, nothing is hidden, revealed, changed.

I'm stumped as to why things bind initially when I pass in the parameters and looks good using same code of data-bind="text: name", but doesn't update with nearly identical code of: data-bind="text: selectedItem".

Did I miss a step or screw something up in my view model?

Comment: You need to call your observables as function when assigning values to them. e.g. `self.selectedItem(item)` instead of `self.selectedItem = item`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined both `isOpen` and `selectedItem` as `ko.observable`.

So, when you want to change their values, you should use them as methods:

```
self.isOpen(false);
self.selectedItem(item);
```

And the same, when you want to get those values:

```
self.isOpen();
self.selectedItem();
```

So, I've changed your code to fix those issues, and it appears to be working:

```js
ko.components.register('text-list', {
    viewModel: function (params) {
        var self = this;
        // Data
        this.name = ko.observable(params.name);
        this.info = params.info;
        this.items = params.items;
        this.isOpen = ko.observable(true);
        this.selectedItem = ko.observable('');

        // Behaviors
        this.selectFacet = function (item) {
            self.selectedItem(item);
            self.isOpen(false);
        }.bind(this);

        this.useAny = function () {
            self.selectedItem('Any');
            self.isOpen(false);
        }.bind(this);

        this.remove = function () {
            self.selectedItem('');
            self.isOpen(true);
        }.bind(this);

    },
    template:
      '<li class="list-group-item text-list-facet">\
        <div class="row header-row">\
            <div class="col-md-12">\
                <div class="row">\
                    <div class="col-md-4">\
                        <p class="text-left">\
                            <b><small data-bind="text: name"></small></b>\
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign infoicon" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-bind="attr: { title: info }"></span>\
                        </p>\
                    </div>\
                    <div class="col-md-4">\
                        <p class="text-center selected-choice" data-bind="text: selectedItem"></p>\
                    </div>\
                    <div class="col-md-4">\
                        <p class="text-right">\
                            <span data-bind="visible: isOpen">\
                                <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" data-bind="click: useAny"><small>use any</small> <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>\
                            </span>\
                            <span data-bind="visible: !isOpen">\
                                <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" data-bind="click: remove"><small>remove</small> <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>\
                            </span>\
                        </p>\
                    </div>\
                </div>\
            </div>\
        </div>\
        <div class="row content-row" data-bind="visible: isOpen">\
            <div class="col-md-12">\
                <ul class="list-inline" data-bind="foreach: items">\
                    <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-link specul" data-bind="text: $data, click: $parent.selectFacet"></button></li>\
                </ul>\
            </div>\
        </div>\
    </li>'
});


var textListViewModel = function () {
            this.name = 'Test Section';
            this.info = 'This is a tooltip';
            this.items = ['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3'];
        };

//apply with a viewmodel
var $nw = $('<li class="list-group-item text-list-facet"><text-list params="name: name, info: info, items: items"></text-list></li>');

$('#test-ul').append($nw);
ko.applyBindings(textListViewModel, $nw[0]);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<ul id='test-ul'></ul>
```

Comment: Ok, so I just found another bug I had with `visible: isOpen` and `visible: !isOpen` where the former worked fine, but the latter required a function call for it to evaluate properly, so `visible: !isOpen()`